# How does the following return dict syntax works?

Tags: python

Sorry for being noob .
Reading some code and came across this how is the syntax in return is  interpreted?

```
def get_constants(prefix):
"""Create a dictionary mapping socket module constants to their names."""
return dict((getattr(socket, n), n)
            for n in dir(socket)
            if n.startswith(prefix)
            )
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just `dict` being given a sequence of name/value pairs produced by the generator expression

```
(getattr(socket, n), n) for n in dir(socket) if n.startswith(prefix).
```

A simpler example of the same usage:

```
>>> dict((x, 1) for x in range(2))
{0: 1, 1: 1}
```

Comment: Your example, and OP's example, can also be expressed with the equivalent form `{x: 1 for x in range(2)}`

Comment: Yes, but the confusion here seems to be what exactly is being passed to `dict` as an argument.

Comment: Indeed, I think your answer is good the way it is. My comment is for context in case OP wants to refactor later. =)

Comment: The dict comprehension version is more idiomatic IMO, especially if you're already writing a generator expression.